# Google Map Autocomplete with Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, laravel, autocomplete

Trying to add google autocomplete in Laravel. My code is like follows-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
        var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('txtPlaces'));
        google.maps.event.addListener(places, 'place_changed', function () {

        });
    });
</script>
<span>Location:</span>
<input type="text" id="txtPlaces" style="width: 250px" placeholder="Enter a location" />
```

Its absolutely works in HTML / PHP file. The output in html/php file is like that-

[image]

However, when I wanna implement in **Laravel**, its not working at all. It shows the following error. 
[image]

Can you help me to fixed this one?

Comment: which google api script file you included?

Comment: @DharaParmar, its update now... 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>

Comment: where you inject your API key?

Comment: In raw html/php file, it works fine without API key..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add key in url, the reason of this error is that you haven't configured your Google Maps API keys yet.

Refer to see - How to create key: http://docs.gravityview.co/article/306-signing-up-for-a-google-maps-api-key

Add key to url:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR API KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

or use this url:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
```

Comment: I followed you... however, not fixed yet... now no more error but no output tooo

Comment: can you provide me the key?

Comment: sure... 

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBUuzpxkwNy9beYbH0Io0PPRJKBtR0GDJM&libraries=places"></script>

Comment: Use this url:  `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>`

Comment: I used this, and got the same error... http://i.stack.imgur.com/fMI6o.png